# Electromagnetic compatibility problem with an hairdryer

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, electricity, electromagnetic, emi-filtering

I wanted to ask you if you could give me an explanation of this electromagnetic compatibility problem.

I connected my (fully working) TV to a certain electrical socket in my house. I have also a very low cost hairdryer, and I have noticed that each time I connect it to the same socket of my TV (precisely: a socket which comes from the same wires behind the wall), and switch the hairdryer on the antenna signal on my TV disappears. The problem is solved as soon as I remove the hairdryer from the supply socket.

So, I was looking for a possible explanation of this phenomenon, and a possible circuital model. I think it means that, since it is a low cost device, it does not fill the EMC requirements correctly. But what does it happen from a circuital/electromagnetic point of view?

I wanted to analyze this phenomenon with more detail, but I do not know if it is an inductive coupling, a capacitive coupling, a radiation problem etc

Comment: "*each time I connect it to the same socket of my TV ...*" even if you don't switch it on?

Comment: And you've tried both on a different outlet?

Comment: @Transistor no, if I do not switch the hairdryer on, the signal is perfect

Comment: @EasyOhm no, unfortunately it is not so easy  because my TV is fixed on the wall, I'll see if I found a cable to try it on another outlet

Comment: EMI issue. First line of defense would be an X1 capacitor straight across the motor inside the hairdryer, but it’s probably not worth the hassle considering your time and what a EMC compliant hairdryer costs.

Comment: But is that spurious voltage through the TV supply line or through the antenna cable?

Comment: Most likely supply line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation, TV or other communication signal works on `Radio Waves`, which are nothing but varying electric field and magnetic field. The hair drier has a motor in it, which has brushes to make electrical contact with the armature. When the motor rotates it created a varying magnetic field and electrical field across the brushes that can be see in the form of spark. This is called the back `emf`, in order to suppress `EM` interference such devices comes with a small capacitor in parallel with the motor. you hair drier motor might not have that. Also, the varying inductance interfere with the line voltage that may also cause `EM`interference. 
other possibility could be, Your TV signal may be weak hence getting impacted with the EM interference.

I used to play with elf made electromagnet bell made with just a single relay during childhood when i observed, this effect.

Comment: A radio wave is an electric field and magnetic field operating in unison. A radio wave IS NOT nothing but a varying magnetic field.

Comment: You are right, I missed electric field

Answer (score 0):

the motor creates sparks. Sparks are tiny lightning bolts, with fast onset of charge movement. The fast onset (fast risetime) easily triggers an evil ringing in channel-selection circuits, blanking out your tuner.